# AngularJS: Access models using dynamic names in template

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-ng-click, angular-ngmodel

I have a template with a lot of what is essentially duplicate code. I'd like to use a directive to include a partial template which I can manipulate for each "block" of duplicate code.

The template currently looks something like this:

```
<div class="column book">
    <div class="header">
        <input type="text" id="book_query" ng-model="book_query.name" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="book in books | filter:book_query">
            {{book.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
....
<div class="column game">
    <div class="header">
        <input type="text" id="game_query" ng-model="game_query.name" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="game in games | filter:game_query">
            {{game.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
....
```

And the controller just gets the data and adds it to the scope e.g.

```
$scope.books = data.books;
$scope.games = data.games;
```

What I started doing was using a directive which takes in an argument (e.g. book, game etc) so I then knew which model(s) to use. The problem I have is how to use the argument to access the model in the template? The directive itself is, currently, very simple:

```
<div item-column item="book"></div>
<div item-column item="game"></div>

app.directive('itemColumn', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            item: '@'
        },
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'item_column.html'
    };
});
```

In item_column.html, I was hoping I could just substitute the item argument, which works fine for displaying the value of the arg but not for replacing where 'book' or 'game' is used for the models e.g.

```
<div class="column {{item}}">
    <div class="header">
        <input type="text" id="{{item}}_query" ng-model="{{item}}_query.name" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in ??? | filter:{{item}}_query">
            {{item.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone show me the best way of doing this? I don't doubt I'm going the complete wrong way about it!

EDIT: The original issue above is now pretty much fully solved using JoseM's answer below. The one outstanding issue is the on-click functions on each element no longer firing the parent scope from within the isolated scope.

My controller is laid out like so:

```
    app.controller('ItemsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'CONFIG', function($scope, $http, CONFIG) {

    var items = ['books', 'games'];

    items.forEach(function(item) {
        $scope[item] = [];
        $scope['selected_'+item] = null;
    })

    $scope.getItem = function(item) {

        $http.get('?action=get_item&id='+item.id+'&type='+item.type)
            .success(function(data) {
                // update model
            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                // do something
            });
    }
}]);
```

$scope.getItem is no longer accessible when clicking on the item in the view, which looks similar to the following after implementing JoseM's answer:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in array | filter:query">
    <div class="text" ng-click="getItem(item)">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a simple way of making the parent scope functions available from within the isolated scope? Or is there a better place for these functions? Apologies for (what I feel are) the very basic questions - I'm still trying to get my head around Angular!

Comment: You can pass a function to template and create your own template dynamically

Comment: That's true, and it should work. The problem is, and it's not obvious from the question as I've simplified it somewhat, but there's a significant amount of code in the template. Ideally, I don't really want this in a JS file - I'd much rather have it contained in a separate html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish what you want is by using a child scope in your directive and then doing your own "linking" of the parent scope variables using a watch on the parent scope value.

in your directive:

```
app.directive('itemColumn', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'item_column.html',
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {
          var varName = scope.varName = attrs.item;
          var parScope = scope.$parent;
          parScope.$watch(varName + 's', function(newVal){
            scope.theArray = newVal;
          });
          parScope.$watch(varName + '_query', function(newVal){
            scope.theQuery = newVal;
          });
        }
    };
});
```

in your template:

```
<div class="column {{varName}}">
    <div class="header">
        <input type="text" ng-attr-id="{{varName}}_query" ng-model="theQuery.name" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in theArray | filter:theQuery">
            {{item.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to use an isolated scope, you could it, but then you would have to supply at least 3 attributes if you are using the same properties as above.  I personally believe that using an isolated scope is a better way of doing it.  See below how the isolated version is simpler:

isolated version of directive

```
app.directive('itemColumn2', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
          label: '@',
          array: '=',
          query: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'item_column2.html'
    };
});
```

isolated version of template

```
<div class="column {{label}}">
    <div class="header">
        <input type="text" ng-attr-id="{{label}}_query" ng-model="query.name" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in array | filter:query">
            {{item.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

usage

```
<div item-column2 label="book" array="books" query="book_query"></div>
<div item-column2 label="game" array="games" query="game_query"></div>
```

And finally here is a sample plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OyEHR4ZhzYKvs4jeDfjD?p=preview

Comment: The isolated scope method works fantastically, thanks a lot! The only issue I now have with it is there's a few functions which were being called in the parent scope when clicking on elements in the UI, which no longer work with the isolated scope. Is there an easy way to link them back up? I'll update the original issue with some details.

Comment: Actually, it's all good. I appear to have sorted the issue by sending the function in as another argument. Thanks for your help!